# How to handle links that don't start with http, https in nextjs Link component

Tags: hyperlink, next.js

I am trying to make `nextjs` `Link` component to redirect correctly to a website that don't have a `http, https` in it i am storing links in database based on what user writes and some of them don't inclue `http, https` but for some reason the `Link` component appends these links to my current website url for example:

`google.com` will redirect to `mywebsite.com/google.com`

any possible way to resolve this issue

i have tried searching online with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am on a URL such as:

```
http://example/
```

And I write a link like this:

```
<a href="foo" />hi</a>
```

Then clicking the link will go to:

```
http://example/foo
```

So if your link look like:

```
<a href="google.com" />hi</a>
```

Then the expected behavior is for that link to go to:

```
 http://example/google.com
```

So this is all exactly as expected. If you have links stored in the database that were supposed to include `https://`, then you need to add that before writing your links.